# Is spaces.Discrete appropriate for representing an integer range?

Tags: openai-gym

I want to represent something like hit points ranging 0-100 in my environment's observation space, along with some other stuff. My first idea was to use `Tuple` to tie together a `Box` for hit points with some `Discrete`s for other things.

However, I've been using Stable Baselines, and it appears they don't support Tuple. I do see support for MultiDiscrete, and I *could* stuff hit points into a `Discrete(100)`, but I worry that this would lose the context that 51 is very close to 52, and not completely different like 1.

Is using Discrete like this wrong?

Comment: What part in the Stable Baselines do you want to use? You could modify that part to make it compatible with Tuple. I am guessing it has got to do something with the creation of the networks.

Comment: Do you mean which model? I'm not particular. I chose A2C because it had a healthy support matrix for observation and action spaces. Not sure I'm at the level of being able to modify models.

Comment: As far as I know, the observation space is just used to initialise the networks. So you could just modify those parts and check if it helps. If you are looking into some specific problem and need more help with it, you might have to share some code here to modify.

Comment: I haven't figured out the answer to "Is spaces.Discrete correct to represent a range of integers", but I wanted to share what I ended up doing. As well documented as stable baselines is, I switched over to RLlib for its support of parametric observation spaces. spaces.Box is working well for integer ranges in RLlib.